# Putting the result of a function as the text of a link

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I have an algorithm that is sorting through various combinations until a pre-given string is matched. I want the results of this algorithm to appear as the innerHtml of a link. 
this is the code I have tried, but the link isn't active.

UPDATE: 
I'm using p5.js 
Text appears on the page in the position I want and it is also running through the algorithm but the text doesn't lead to the link that I want.

jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/4xn037v8/

```
<a id="logo" href="link.com"></a>
<script>

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    bestPhrase = createP(document.getElementsByTagName(logo));
    bestPhrase.position(15, 20);
    bestPhrase.class("best");


    target = "link.com";

    function draw() {
      if (population.isFinished()) {
        noLoop();
      }
      displayInfo();
    }

    function displayInfo() {
      // Display current status of population
      let answer = population.getBest();
      bestPhrase.html(answer);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think this description lacks some details. I can't connect things you say you want to achieve with this piece of code.

Comment: Seems like you're missing enough details for us to know how to help. Take a look here for advice on how to improve your question: [mcve]

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: If you use jQuery replace `html` with `text` in the last line: `bestPhrase.text(answer);`

Comment: What do you mean _the link isn't active_? Do you mean your text does not show up, or do you mean nothing happens when you click on the link?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm using p5.js

Comment: Jay - You need to take a step back and try to understand the fundamentals of what you are attempting to do. For example, the p5 `createP()` method requires a string to be passed into it, yet you are passing something remarkably different. The `document.getElemementsByTagName(logo));` returns a HTMLCollection which is not a string of HTML. Beyond that, you've provided no reference to the `population` object so we have no idea what `population.getBest()` actually does. We cannot help you if we can't determine what your intent is or what your code is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @LukeGarrigan - sure we can guess, but your snarky comment adds no value. In an attempt to help the OP, I pointed out WHY we need to KNOW and not guess. If the return from `population.getBest()` happens to be something like an HTMLCollection object (as is the case in other parts of the OP's code) then things won't work out so well.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Here is a jsFiddle of what I'm trying to do. I don't understand javascript too well https://jsfiddle.net/4xn037v8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `target` is a URL and the `answer` is expected to resolve to that URL, and you want that URL should be hyperlinked.

You would need to add an `a` element with `href` attribute. Then let *that* be `bestPhrase` instead of the `p` element.

So you could prepare that `a` at the start of the `setup` function, as follows:

```
let container = createP("Best phrase:");
container.position(10,10);
container.class("best");
target = "google.com";
bestPhrase = createA("http://" + target, "");
bestPhrase.parent(container);
```

No change in the `display` function is needed.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgc05j1x/)

Comment: Great answer, is createA a p5 function? I can't find it in the reference.